# MS SQL Server configured for secure (SSL) connection allows non-secure connection from JDBC Client

Tags: sql-server, ssl, jdbc, security

I need to connect to the MS SQL Server 2008 r2 using the secure communication. I have been able to do the same using the following connection string:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://<<db server name>>:1433;databaseName=<<db name>>;selectMethod=cursor;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;integratedSecurity=false;trustStore=<<path to my trust store>>;trustStorePassword=<<password>>
```

On the DB server I have used Configuration Manager to specify the certificate to be used and enable 'Forced Encryption' 
   SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for <> - Right Click -> Properties -> Force Encryption and Certificate

however, I am able to connect to the same DB without specifying 'encrypt=true' that is with the following URL:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://<<db server name>>:1433;databaseName=<<db name>>;selectMethod=cursor;
```

My confusion is that when SQL Server has been configured for secure connection, shouldn't it reject/ignore the non-encypted connection. Or do I need to do addtional configuration so the DB server accepts only secure connections

Thanks and Regards
P Manchanda

Answer (score 4):

No. As per documentation it will have a encrypted connnection.

Check http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bde679d9-ff83-4fa7-b402-42e336a97106/force-encryption-on-sql-server-not-working

> When the Force Encryption option for the Database Engine is set to
>   YES, all communications between client and server is encrypted no
>   matter whether the “Encrypt connection” option (such as from SSMS) is
>   checked or not. You can check it using the following DMV statement.

Simple like that - your connection string setting is ignored.

This can be checked on the server via:

```
USE master
GO
SELECT encrypt_option FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I ran the above mentioned query and it returned 2 rows both with the value of 'TRUE'. So, I suppose this indicates that my DB Server is configured to accept encrypted connections.